# Cant get the response number from HttpResponse

Tags: android, post

I have a piece of code that sends post packet to somewhere.
I want to output to my screen the status code, eg 200 for OK, or 400 for bad request..
either the number or the string, what i have at the moment:

```
response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
```

where response is an HttpResponse, but i need to compare it to HttpStatus.SC_OK or whatever.
the post is happening inside an AsyncTask class, which executes the post.execute() object.
the return value is some "com.example.....postAsync@#NUMBER#". the number is something random, not a response type.
what should i do?

Edit: Some more code:

```
HttpResponse response = null;
StringEntity tmp = null;
HttpPost httpPost = null;
DefaultHttpClient httpClient;
HttpContext localContext;
    public String post(String url,String data) {
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        localContext = new BasicHttpContext(); 
        String ret = "";
        try {
            tmp = new StringEntity("value={ \"n\": " + data + " }","UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        httpPost.setEntity(tmp);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);
            if (response != null) {
                ret = "" + response.getEntity();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Its like im getting the content of the response, where im only interested if its sent ok or not.

Comment: I added almost the entire class. the postAsync is a AsyncTask that uses this post method

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode(); // This will be 200 or 404, etc.
```

Comment: I tried. it doesnt seem any different than what i tried. but i still receive some string as described before, not 200/404 or whatever.

Comment: Try printing only the int of statusCode, when you print response.getEntity(), it will probably output a random string.

Comment: I keep getting '0' from response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(). even tough my msg was received on the other side. what is wrong?